# how to direct to a HTML Page use Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I mean in a Servlet, I want to direct to a Html Page.
I know `response.sendRedirect("/xxoo/xxoo.html");` can be useful.
The question is the location of the Page,I don't know how to get the right url here.
In the file structure in the project is as bellow:

```
src
├─com
│  └─test
│          BaseServlet.java
│          
└─resources
    └─Pages
            HomePage.html
```

Comment: Buddy use `getContextPath()`. it will be helpful for you. OR if you use `response.sendRedirect("/")` means ROOT directory. From there you can redirect to your location

Comment: @Felix can you open your exploded wr file from your server deployment location.Then give the path relative your application folder to the html file in your `response.sendRedirect("/relative path")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways.

If you start you path with "/" it means you are specifying absolute path from the webapps folder (where application is deployed).
this would be something like:

```
response.sendRedirect("/applicationName/resources/pages/xxoo/xxoo.html");
```

or you can also use relative paths (from current location) by not specifying starting "/" i.e:

```
response.sendRedirect("resources/pages/xxoo/xxoo.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to move you web page to WebContent directory of project.
after that, we can use as below

`response.sendRedirect("direcotyinwebcontent/file.html");`

Comment: Must the page in WebContent?

Comment: yes, if the page in WebContent directory then we can directly use response.sendRedirect method